# java bouncycastle PKCS12 keystore "max password length"

Tags: java, bouncycastle, keystore

For what would seem to be a deceptively easy Google search, I get nothing...

Before digging into the code, does anyone know off-hand what (if any) the max password `char[]` length is for a Bouncy Castle implementation of a PKCS12 type Java KeyStore?

I'm working on a GUI to load a KeyStore object from a file, and I just need to know what to cap the password field length at.

THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PKCS12 uses various key derivation functions such as [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) to transform a password into a fixed-length symmetric key. There is no limit on the length of the password and the BouncyCastle implementation does not add one.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm not talking about aliased entries (key/cert/entry), only the KeyStore.load function itself. Does that same answer apply strictly to that function as well?

Comment: The password for the entire store is usually used to authenticate data, not encrypt it. Otherwise the same answer applies: there is no character limit.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your distinction between authenticate vs encrypt, so I just want to clarify my understanding: The KeyStore object can have a password for the entire KeyStore object, and a separate password for each aliased entry (key/cert/entry) stored in that object.  Aren't those passwords a combination of authentication and cryption? If the raw data stored via ```KeyStore.store(password)`` is not encrypted, then why use a KeyStore object at all, vs just serializing to a file?

Comment: Usually you can list the contents of a PKCS12 file without knowing the password. You just won't be able to verify the keystore's integrity. However to retrieve the private keys you need to provide a password (they are encrypted).

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for explaining that. Regardless though, specifying a password in either case, that password doesn't have a size limit?

Comment: No, in both cases there is no limit.